# Application US20140276230: The word in google patent is garbled and PDF cannot be download

Tags: us20140276230

Application [US20140276230](https://www.google.com/patents/us20140276230)

Poroelastic dynamic mechanical analyzer for determining mechanical properties of biological materials.

The word　of this patent is garbled and the PDF cannot be download from Google Patent.
Hope for a solution.
Thank you

Comment: Google Patent has the PDF now.  The HTML was not displaying the formulas correctly but formulas are not handled well in many formats.    If you cannot get a PDF from Google in the future, you should try www.pat2pdf.org for a download of the PDF.

Comment: instead of using google.com/patents, try patents.google.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the public PAIR at USPTO:   http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair

Prove you are human with the CAPTCHA and enter 20140276230 in the publication number slot ... look at the published documents ... it's all there.

You will need a TIFF veiwer to look at this document from the USPTO:

http://pdfaiw.uspto.gov/.aiw?PageNum=0&docid=20140276230&IDKey=CACD84DC14F2&HomeUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fappft.uspto.gov%2Fnetacgi%2Fnph-Parser%3FSect1%3DPTO1%2526Sect2%3DHITOFF%2526d%3DPG01%2526p%3D1%2526u%3D%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.html%2526r%3D1%2526f%3DG%2526l%3D50%2526s1%3D20140276230.PGNR.%2526OS%3DDN%2F20140276230%2526RS%3DDN%2F20140276230

Free TIFF Viewer: http://www.alternatiff.com/

Answer (score 1):

I find [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/) a good and generally more reliable alternative to Google Patents. Here is the cited patent application on The Lens: https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/US_2014_0276230_A1.